# How to get active connections in LDAP in command prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, cmd, ldap, devops

I am working with LDAP and it connecting from my spring boot services, Now I need to get no of active connections in LDAP  by using command prompt or any tool while multi users are accessing my Service.
Is there any way to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use 'ldapsearch' utility provided by opendj for findng these. Please refer: https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a93021227.

Comment: Thank you, Its worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the comment we can track the active connections are using ldapsearch

> $ ./ldapsearch --port 389 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager"
>   --bindPassword password --baseDN "cn=monitor" --searchScope sub --trustAll "(objectClass=*)" *